# "Dayful of work" - valid English?

Tags: meaning

Is "after a dayful of work" valid English?

Actually, is "dayful" a valid English word? Because I can't find it in all major online dictionaries, but I'm very sure people are using this word.

Comment: You sure it it isn't 'after a day full of work'? Never heard dayful before. I have heard all in a day's work but never dayful.

Comment: Certainly "a day full" of work is valid.  And it would commonly be pronounced as "dayful".  So using that spelling would not be terribly inappropriate.  But using the test that the natural-sounding plural would "days full" and not "dayfuls", it's probably better left as two words.

Comment: As A.P. suggests, you could use "after a day's work" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't sound idiomatic at all. And I couldn't find "dayful" in any modern dictionary either.

If you mean the person did something after working hard for the entire day, consider **after a hard day's work** instead:

> How to Reduce Stress after a Hard Day’s Work

([www.stim.org](http://www.stim.org/imagerie/stress/reducing-stress/))

> “Good rest after a hard day's work”

([tripadvisor.com](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g154914-d185693-r156114323-Quality_Inn_West_Edmonton-Edmonton_Alberta.html))

Or simply **after a day's work**, as per Hot Licks' comment below.

Comment: The day doesn't need to be "hard".  "All in a day's work."

Comment: No argument there. Somehow a day filled with work implied a hard day to me. But yeah, you're right, thanks for your comment.